# Running 2 Effects on the same selector using script.aculo.us

Tags: scriptaculous

can you call Effect.Move and Effect.Appear on the same selector using scriptaculous or will one cancel out the other. If so whats a way around this as one runs slightly before the uder finishes.

Comment: IS there Anyone can help with this

Answer (score 0):

use **Effect.Parallel**
 For example:

```
 new Effect.Parallel([
     new Effect.Move('element', { sync: true, x: 100, y:300, mode: 'relative' }),
     new Effect.Appear('element',{ from: 1.0, to: 0.3 })
 ], { 
     duration: 1.0,
     delay: 0.5
 });
```

[Effect.Parallel](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-parallel/)